Geometry Nodes copy location as a single action. Parenting conflict
I have a camera rig set to a GN object. The camera is moved back on its z axis to I can pivot around the GN object. The GN object has visible information that has it used as a hud. Information about current frame, etc. I want to essentially be able to switch to normal camera origin so I’m rotating from the cameras position, like you do normally. I think I’ve got it figured out by offsetting the visual geometry. But it requires I do some copy paste to where ever the camera is in world space. I would like to in one action, copy the GN object to where the camera is and offset the visible geometry, creating a seamless transition. I don’t know how to do that. It’s more something that an addon would perform I would think. I’m asking if there is a way to do this. If I’m not making sense I’ll rephrase.

Can you post some images or something to break down what your problem is/ what you're aiming for? Problems like this are hard to wrap your head around just reading them through text.
